# How to come back to the previous page

Tags: javascript

This may be a very easy one, but I am having problem while using `onclick="javascript:history.back(-1);"` with PHP.  In the first page, I get a search result and I have used a post action to get the search criteria.  From this page, I can view the details of the search result.  When I go back to the search result page for IE, I get nothing but the page displays "webpage has expired."

What can I do about this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you to all of you. What i did here is stored the post values in session and displayed the result in different page. 
Stackoverflow has been great support for me and really happy as i have got solutions each time.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the POST/redirect/GET pattern:

- http://www.theserverside.com/patterns/thread.tss?thread_id=20936
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

It seems that IE is not re-posting the form when you go back to that page. Have you considered using a GET request for your search?

Answer (score 0):

The problem (probably) is that you may be using POST request to generate the search results.

Just my curiosity: which version of IE are you using?!

Answer (score 0):

Try posting the form to itself (the same page) instead of another page, then if there is an error you don't have to 'go back' because you are already there! Simply print out the form again and fill in the values that were posted along with a message that something in the form didn't validate.